# Why does [].concat(...arr) help to flatten nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just began learning about javascript a month ago. Was reading up the [Array.prototype.flat() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to solve a problem, and I couldn't figure out why the solution works the way it work.

They wrote about alternative methods to flatten an array, and used reduce and concat at follows:

```js
const arr0 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];

// To flat single level array
const arr1 = arr0.flat();
console.log(arr1) // [1, 2, 3, 4]

// is equivalent to
const arr2 = arr0.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
console.log(arr2) // [1, 2, 3, 4]

// or with decomposition syntax
const flattened = arr => [].concat(...arr);

const arr3 = flattened(arr0)
console.log(arr3)
```

The usual `acc.concat(val)` makes sense to me. What I don't understand is the decompositional syntax part. From my understanding, when you use `.concat(...arr)`, the spread operator will pass all the values of `arr` into the `.concat` method, which means it should be `[1, 2, [3,4]]`. Why is it that it actually flattened the 1 level deep nested array in the process to return `[1,2,3,4]`?

Clearly I am understanding something incorrectly. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is very useful

Comment: it is equivalent to `[].concat(1,2,[3,4])`. Passing an array to concat merges the contents of that array into the callee.

Comment: ...and passing a non-array just adds the element itself, that's the key here

Answer (score 1):

`concat` function can take `number` (or other non-array values) as parameter(s) or another `array`(s) of something and will merge those arguments to 1 array.

Those inputs are same:

`[].concat(1,2, [3,4])` is equal to `[].concat([1], [2], [3,4])`.

Following examples might help you understand:

```js
const test1 = [].concat([3,4])           // [3,4]
const test2 = [].concat(1)               // [1]
const test3 = [].concat(1, 2)            // [1, 2]
const test4 = [].concat(1, 2, [3,4])     // [1,2,3,4]
const test5 = [].concat([1], [2], [3,4]) // [1,2,3,4]
const test6 = [].concat(0, [1,2,[3,4]])  // [0,1,2, [3,4]]
console.log(test6) // it won't flatten deep nested
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! After seeing you type out [].concat(1,2, [3,4]) helped me realize where my misunderstanding was.

Answer (score 1):

> The usual acc.concat(val) makes sense to me. What I don't understand is the decompositional syntax part. From my understanding, when you use .concat(...arr), the spread operator will pass all the values of arr into the .concat method, **which means it should be [1, 2, [3,4]]**. Why is it that it actually flattened the 1 level deep nested array in the process to return [1,2,3,4]?

Almost right - it is not `[1, 2, [3, 4]]` though (that would be an array again) but it would be a tuple of `1, 2, [3, 4]`.

Writing `fn(1, ...[2, 3, 4], 5)` is the same as `fn(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. So in this case, we are doing `[].concat(...[1, 2, [3, 4]])` which is the same as `[].concat(1, 2, [3, 4])`, so `concat` is called with three arguments: `1`, `2` and `[3, 4]`.

The last puzzle piece is that **`concat` behaves differently for arrays and non-arrays as arguments** (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)):

> The `concat` method creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on which it is called, followed in order by, for each argument, **the elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the argument itself (if the argument is not an array)**. It does not recurse into nested array arguments.

This means that `[1, 2].concat(3, [4], 5, [6, 7], 8)` produces an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` because the arguments `123` and `[123]` are handled the same. This differentiation between arrays and non-array values in the arguments to `concat` is what causes the "flattening effect", because it means that `[].concat(1, 2, [3, 4])` is valid and returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Usually, `concat` is used with arrays, and I myself normally consider `x.concat(y, z)` as the same as `[...x, ...y, ...z]` (which wouldn't cause any flattening) but in fact it does support non-array arguments and handles them the same way as if they were the only element in an array - in my example it would be the same as `[...x, ...Array.isArray(y) ? y : [y], ...Array.isArray(z) ? z : [z]]` which actually is the same as `[...x, ...[y, z].flat()]`! - I haven't seen non-array arguments to `concat` used much but it works and that's the key reason why `[].concat(...arr)` does a one-level-deep flattening!

(By the way, this also applies to the `reduce` example. It should actually have made equally little sense to you!)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, and pointing out exactly where I was mistaken! Now it makes sense! :D

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, this will flatten only Array with 1 level sub array. If your array having multiple levels, for example `[1,2,[3,[5,[6]]]]`, this won't flatten the whole array.**

---

In your syntax, `array.concat(another_array)` concat the array passed as argument to the array calling the `concat` method. Here, *another_array* will be added to *array*. `concat` will accept multiple arguments.

```js
let a = [1,2,3], b = [4,5,6], c = [7,8,9];

console.log(a.concat(b,c))
console.log(b.concat(c,a));
```

> concat won't alter original array.

`concat` can also accept individual elements and will add it to the array, just like `push`.

Example

```js
let a = [1,2,3];
a = a.concat(4,5,6);
console.log(a)
```

**B**y using the spread syntax `...`, you are destructuring the array elements and pass the first 2 as individual elements and next one as an array ( `(1,2,[3,4])`).

`concat` will consider this as 3 arguments and concat this to the empty array you're calling the method on.